# JSONata group by multiple fields and count

Tags: jsonata

Does anyone know how to user jsonata to group by multiple fields and count ?
https://docs.jsonata.org/

I can't figure it out, I have been using the jsonata online playground but I can't seem to get anywhere.

I have an array of objects and I want to group by multiple fields and count

I have been doing this earlier in mysql and it is very simple but now when the "records" are json objects I am bit lost and need help

The result should be a new array with the grouped fields + count of the grouped fields

Thanks,
Jani

Comment: Would you mind providing an example input and the desired output for it?

Comment: Yes, from this: https://gist.github.com/ruohomaa/ddf766c83f859cd2ddb520a634cfef89
to this: https://gist.github.com/ruohomaa/f52a2ace920ac7c06dc16afc34094735

Comment: I tried creating something like this but it does not work, I can't get it to count the distinct key `API_TYPEAPI_VERSIONMETHOD_NAME` from the whole array. I am obviously doing it wrong.
https://gist.github.com/ruohomaa/6d3e5667e0e53076faa37a7edc196fad

Comment: There is a distinct function but I can't figure out how to use that for an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hacky solution, but I think it does what you want:

```
$${
  API_TYPE & API_VERSION & METHOD_NAME: {
    "API_TYPE": [API_TYPE][0],
    "API_VERSION": [API_VERSION][0],
    "METHOD_NAME": [METHOD_NAME][0],
    "COUNT": $count($)
  }
} ~> $each(function($value) {$value})
```

The trick is to use the [grouping feature](https://docs.jsonata.org/sorting-grouping#grouping), and group by all three parameters by concatenating them to a single string.

See it in action: https://stedi.link/L1a9Tiv